# Problems in UART communication using Nexys 3 board

Tags: fpga, verilog, uart, xilinx, ise

I am trying to send 1 byte of data from my Nexys 3 board to my PC using UART communication.

The problem is that whenever I try to view the data on RealTerm no matter my input (hard coded into the code or given via switches), the transmitted data always shows 0. I checked by simulating the entire thing but there the code was working as expected.

Can someone help me solve this bug?

Code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module top( input sys_clk,
input sys_rst,
input [7:0] c,
output tx_done,
output uart_tx 

    );
wire [7:0] w_c;
assign w_c = c;

reg [31:0] counter;
reg tx_wr1;
wire w_tx_wr;
assign w_tx_wr = tx_wr1;




uart_tx tx(
.sys_clk(sys_clk),
.sys_rst(sys_rst),
.tx_data(w_c),
.tx_wr(w_tx_wr),
.tx_done(tx_done),
.uart_tx(uart_tx)
);

always @(posedge sys_clk) begin
if(sys_rst == 0 ) begin
    counter <= 32'd0;
    tx_wr1<= 1'd0;
end
else begin

    counter <= counter + 32'd1;
        if (counter == 2) begin
        tx_wr1 <= 1'd1;
        end
        else tx_wr1 <= 1'd0;
end
end

endmodule

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


module uart_tx(
    input sys_rst,
    input sys_clk,


    output reg uart_tx,




    input [7:0] tx_data,
    input tx_wr,
    output reg tx_done
);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// enable16 generator
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
reg [15:0] enable16_counter;
reg [15:0] divisor;
parameter [15:0] BAUD = 16'd651;

wire enable16;
assign enable16 = (enable16_counter == 16'd0);

always @(posedge sys_clk) 
begin
    if(sys_rst==0) begin
        enable16_counter <= divisor - 16'b1;
        divisor <= BAUD;
    end
    else begin 
        enable16_counter <= enable16_counter - 16'd1;
        if(enable16)
            enable16_counter <= divisor - 16'b1;
         end
end 

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// UART TX Logic
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
reg tx_busy;
reg [3:0] tx_bitcount;
reg [3:0] tx_count16;
reg [7:0] tx_reg;

always @(posedge sys_clk) begin
    if(sys_rst==0) begin
        tx_done <= 1'b0;
        tx_busy <= 1'b0;
        uart_tx <= 1'b1;
    end else begin
        tx_done <= 1'b0;
        if(tx_wr) begin
            tx_reg <= tx_data;
            tx_bitcount <= 4'd0;
            tx_count16 <= 4'd1;
            tx_busy <= 1'b1;
            uart_tx <= 1'b0;
`ifdef SIMULATION
            $display("UART: %c", tx_data);
`endif
        end else if(enable16 && tx_busy) begin
            tx_count16  <= tx_count16 + 4'd1;

            if(tx_count16 == 4'd0) begin
                tx_bitcount <= tx_bitcount + 4'd1;
                
                if(tx_bitcount == 4'd8) begin
                    uart_tx <= 1'b1;
                end else if(tx_bitcount == 4'd9) begin
                    uart_tx <= 1'b1;
                    tx_busy <= 1'b0;
                    tx_done <= 1'b1;
                    $display("Transmission done");
                end else begin
                    uart_tx <= tx_reg[0];
                    tx_reg <= {1'b0, tx_reg[7:1]};
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

endmodule

////////////////////////TestBench///////////////////////////////////////////////////

`timescale 1ns / 1ps

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer:
//
// Create Date:   23:30:56 01/03/2023
// Design Name:   top
// Module Name:   D:/testb/simu.v
// Project Name:  testb
// Target Device:  
// Tool versions:  
// Description: 
//
// Verilog Test Fixture created by ISE for module: top
//
// Dependencies:
// 
// Revision:
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments:
// 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module simu;

    // Inputs
    reg sys_clk;
    reg sys_rst;
    reg [7:0] c;

    // Outputs
    wire tx_done;
    wire uart_tx;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    top uut (
        .sys_clk(sys_clk), 
        .sys_rst(sys_rst), 
        .c(c),
        .tx_done(tx_done), 
        .uart_tx(uart_tx)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        sys_clk = 0;
        sys_rst = 0;
        c = 0;
        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #100 sys_rst = 1;
       c = 10 ;
        // Add stimulus here
 
    end
     always #5 sys_clk = ~sys_clk; 
endmodule
```

Simulation output:

[image]

`tx_done` indicates that the transmission of 1 byte has been done successfully.

[image]

Output as shown on the RealTerm window. No matter the input, the transmitted value remains the same.

Comment: I get no issues whatsoever with your design running on an Arty A7 board. I get one symbol, selectable with onboard switches/buttons, pushed out at 9600 baud after each reset pressed. The putty shows exactly one character sent with the correct code. So look for the issues at the physical side of your testbench. Maybe wrong pin assignment, maybe wrong usb connector used or wrong virtual com port selected in terminal...

Comment: @Vlad thanks for the reply. It was a problem at the hardware part. When we used a FTD232RL to send the data to the computer it was able to send the data.